# Firefox on Mac: Scroll 1 line per mouse tick?

Tags: firefox, mouse, scrolling

I use a G700 on a Mac (10.12.5).

When in Atom, a single *tick* of my mouse wheel makes the editor scroll a single line.

When in Firefox (53.0.3), a single tick of the mouse wheel does not scroll at all. I need at least 3 - 4 ticks per second (i.e., give the wheel some momentum or make it actually go around) for Firefox to start scrolling.

How can I configure (e.g., `about:config`) Firefox to behave like Atom: I would like it to scroll approximately a single line when I tick the wheel forward?